# Insert operation based on conditions in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck at a position where I need to do an insert operation for 'n' number of chapters on one submit button and through one insert query basically in a loop.

Now my question is if a user has passed exam for chapter number 3, then I don't  want to insert record for chapter 3. Is this achievable? I've tried to solve this myself but couldn't find a way.

Here is my code:

```
for($i = 1; $i=5; $i++) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_user_reattempt (ID,user_id,chapter_id,days_for _start,days_for_end,created) VALUES ('','$user_id','$chapter_id','$days_for_start','$days_for_end','$created')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

What modifications has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create unique index for 2 fields: `user_id` and `chapter_id`.
2. Use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = ID` in the end of your INSERT query.

Comment: Thanks . but can you explain what the 2nd point you mentioned will perform. Thanks

Comment: First step will add a special behavior to your database that will check two fields for unique values in pair (user_id and passed chapter in your case) and will throw an error on duplicate. The second step asks database to do not throw an exception on duplicate, just update fields (ID = ID means "do nothing") so all duplicates will be ignored by database layer and you don't need to do anything extra from the PHP side.